# How to install AutoRest correctly?

Tags: autorest

I installed nodejs 16.14.0 LTS version on my VM.
I also have dotnet 6 installed on it.
I installed autorest and then when I run the command PS doesn't recognize it at all.
The screenshot below is a Powershell 7 session.
[image]

On another VM it works perfectly fine.

I tried to wipe it out, re-install, uninstall and install again, reset, but nothing helped so far.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make it work I had to add the following path to the User environment variables:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm
```